# Connecting multiple polygons with lines using shortest distance as parameter

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

Is there any plugin in QGIS (or code) that is used to connect multiple polygons with lines using distance as parameter. Let say that I put 10 meters, than all polygons within that distance will be connected with lines where is shortest distance from polygons. Something like on images below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PyQGIS, following code works. It calculates lines for shortest distances between vertices of adjacent features; but distance as parameter is 14 meters instead 10 (it was due to my own polygon layer).

```
import itertools

layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

comb = range(len(feats))

lines = []

for i, j in itertools.combinations(comb, 2):
    d = feats[i].geometry().distance(feats[j].geometry())
    if d < 14:

        vertices1 = [ vertex for vertex in feats[i].geometry().vertices() ]
        vertices2 = [ vertex for vertex in feats[j].geometry().vertices() ]

        dist = []

        for k in range(len(vertices1)):
           for l in range(len(vertices2)):
              dist.append([k,l, vertices1[k].distance(vertices2[l])])
        res = [[i.index(min(i)), min(i)] for i in zip(*dist)][2]

        lines.append([vertices1[dist[res[0]][0]], vertices2[dist[res[0]][1]]])

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "LineString?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'shortest_distances',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(lines)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(lines[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

Above code was run with layer of following image; where it is also observed produced lines.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

Following code also works in QGIS 2.18:

```
import itertools

layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

comb = range(len(feats))

lines = []

for i, j in itertools.combinations(comb, 2):
    d = feats[i].geometry().distance(feats[j].geometry())
    if d < 14:
        print(d)

        vertices1 = feats[i].geometry().asPolygon()[0]
        vertices2 = feats[j].geometry().asPolygon()[0]

        dist = []

        for k in range(len(vertices1)):
           for l in range(len(vertices2)):
              dist.append([k,l, QgsPoint(vertices1[k]).distance(QgsPoint(vertices2[l]))])
        res = [[i.index(min(i)), min(i)] for i in zip(*dist)][2]

        lines.append([vertices1[dist[res[0]][0]], vertices2[dist[res[0]][1]]])

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "LineString?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'shortest_distances',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(lines)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(lines[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

After running it with same shapefile, I got an equivalent result as it can be observed in following image:

[image]

Comment: It seems that your code doesn't work in QGIS 2.18. I got error: AttributeError: 'QgsProject' object has no attribute 'addMapLayer'. Then I tried it in QGIS 3.10 and it works. Is there any way to make it work in QGIS  2.18?

Comment: @Ivan In my **Editing Note** you can observe a code that also works in QGIS 2.18.